# Extracting text from a file name and putting it in a column

Tags: r

**EDIT: To make things as reproducible as possible, I made a dummy bucket on AWS that I will give the credentials for.**

**What I'm trying to accomplish: Create a new column in each dataframe that comes from a CSV file in the S3 bucket called `state_name` that contains the name of the state in the `.csv` file name.**

Here is the access:

```
  Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "AKIAX2TY5WNMXPACEXVV",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "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",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1"
)
```

The first part of the script creates a dataframe based on the file information coming from the S3 bucket. There's also some cleaning that isn't particularly relevant to this question, but I kept in to maintain script integrity.

```
#Retrieves all the items in an S3 bucket.    

    all_buckets <-aws.s3::get_bucket_df(bucket = "so-bucket-test-1222", max = Inf) %>% arrange(desc(LastModified))

    #Filtering out some unnecessary files in the bucket (not super relevant to this question, but keeping it in to maintain script integrity)

    buckets_format <- all_buckets %>% filter(str_detect(Key, '-Algorithm='))

    buckets_script_results <- all_buckets %>% filter(str_detect(Key, '-script_results-')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '-Algorithm=')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '2020'))
```

The next part of the script is creating a character vector with all of the names of the CSV files that are going to be extracted from the S3 bucket, opened, and put it into a dataframe.

```
 #Extracts the key needed to retrieve and open the CSV files in the bucket

    script_results <- buckets_script_results$Key
```

Here is the part where I actually extract the data from the CSVs living in the S3 bucket, and put it all into one dataframe:

```
#This is the actual extraction process where the files are downloaded and put into a dataframe.

    build_list <- lapply(script_results, function(fn) aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, bucket="so-bucket-test-1222", object=fn))

    build_df <- do.call(rbind.fill, archives)
```

So what I am trying to do is build a process into this function that takes the extracted state name from the file name, and then using that to create a new column in each downloaded file that contains the state name.

For example: The `pennsylvania` file will have a new column called `state_name` where all four rows say `pennsylvania`. Same thing for all 939 rows in the `wisconsin` file, and so on...

So the final dataframe should look something like this:

```
final_df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/final_df.csv')
```

**EDIT: From Cazman's answer**

```
Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "AKIAX2TY5WNMXPACEXVV",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "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",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1"
)

all_buckets <-aws.s3::get_bucket_df(bucket = "so-bucket-test-1222", max = Inf) %>% arrange(desc(LastModified))

buckets_script_results <- all_buckets %>% filter(str_detect(Key, '-script_results-')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '-Algorithm=')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '2020'))

script_results <- buckets_script_results$Key

build_func <- function(path) {
  state = str_extract(path, paste(tolower(state_name), collapse = "|"))
  temp = aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, bucket="so-bucket-test-1222", object=path)
  temp['state'] = state
  return(temp)
}

build_list <- lapply(script_results, build_func)
```

Comment: Some feedback on your question: A Github raw link is a nice way to share data **if** you need to share more data than fits comfortably in the question. Here there is one relevant column and your 3 rows of data are a nice minimal example, so `dput(all_buckets[, "Key"])` would put all the data in the question, which keeps it nice and reproducible without an external dependency on your Github account.

Comment: And your first code block seems to be all working just fine, so including it is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think it's very relevant for the question. Again, my question isn't asking if the code here is right. It's asking what a function/loop might look like that creates a new column from each extracted CSV file that contains the state name being taken from the file name. Does that make sense?

Comment: In your rewrite, to help it be reproducible, make it so that we can run it from top to bottom in a fresh R session. In the current version, I can only look at your first code block. The first line runnable to anyone but you is `all_buckets <- read.csv(...)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I rewrote the question to hopefully make it more sequential from top to bottom.

Comment: I see the "EDIT FROM CAZMAN'S ANSWER" as part of your question now, but you don't say anything about it. Is it working, and your problem is solved? Or do you still need help? Why are you including Cazman's answer in your question?

Comment: Sorry been away from my computer. Yes, it is now solved! Thank you so much for both of your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do what @GregorThomas said in regards to finding the state name in the path, but to do it in the context of the function inside the `build_list` `apply()`. I couldn't connect to the AWS database, so I modified everything to read from the GitHub repo, but if I understand the `s3read_using()` function correctly, it will return a data frame from `read.csv()` in this case.

```
s = lapply(script_results, function(x) paste('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datacfb123/testdata/main/', x, sep = ""))
s = unlist(s)

state_name = str_replace(state.name, "\\s", "-")
build_func <- function(path) {
  state = str_extract(path, paste(tolower(state_name), collapse = "|"))
  temp = read.csv(path) %>%
    select(c(1: 7))
  temp['state'] = state
  return(temp)
}

build_list <- lapply(s, build_func)

build_df <- bind_rows(build_list, .id = 'column_label')
```

The head of `build_df`:

```
  column_label       ID ID.Type Voter.First.Name Voter.Last.Name Voter.Phone
1            1  9321329       B       firstname1       lastname1  1234567890
2            1  8958993       B       firstname2       lastname2  1234567891
3            1   119964       B       firstname3       lastname3  1234567892
4            1 12713977       B       firstname4       lastname4  1234567893
5            1 13997387       B       firstname5       lastname5  1234567894
6            1  9813986       B       firstname6       lastname6  1234567895
  Date.Called Time.Called..EST.     state Voter.ID
1    10/16/20      06:30 PM EST wisconsin       NA
2    10/16/20      06:31 PM EST wisconsin       NA
3    10/16/20      06:31 PM EST wisconsin       NA
4    10/16/20      06:31 PM EST wisconsin       NA
5    10/16/20      06:31 PM EST wisconsin       NA
6    10/16/20      06:31 PM EST wisconsin       NA
```

and the tail:

```
     column_label ID ID.Type Voter.First.Name Voter.Last.Name Voter.Phone
1469            4 NA       A     firstname422     lastname422  1234568311
1470            4 NA       A     firstname423     lastname423  1234568312
1471            4 NA       A     firstname424     lastname424  1234568313
1472            4 NA       A     firstname425     lastname425  1234568314
1473            4 NA       A     firstname426     lastname426  1234568315
1474            4 NA       A     firstname427     lastname427  1234568316
     Date.Called Time.Called..EST.          state Voter.ID
1469     9/28/21      07:57 PM EST north-carolina 10248248
1470     9/28/21      07:56 PM EST north-carolina  6290407
1471     9/28/21      07:58 PM EST north-carolina 18397149
1472     9/28/21      07:58 PM EST north-carolina 19520720
1473     9/28/21      07:59 PM EST north-carolina 17216409
1474     9/28/21      08:00 PM EST north-carolina 19273804
```

The only thing I really did was modify the `state.names` to replace spaces with `-` since your paths looked to be formatted that way, and put what @GregorThomas wrote into a function.

With the credentials, `build_func()` turns into:

```
build_func <- function(path) {
  state = str_extract(path, paste(tolower(state_name), collapse = "|"))
  temp = aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, bucket="so-bucket-test-1222", object=path)
  temp['state'] = state
  return(temp)
}
```

and the call is:

```
build_list <- lapply(script_results, build_func)
```

and `head(build_df[, 1:11])`:

```
column_label       ID ID.Type Voter.First.Name Voter.Last.Name Voter.Phone
1            1  7591131       A       firstname1       lastname1  1234567890
2            1  7930949       B       firstname2       lastname2  1234567890
3            1  7371170       B       firstname3       lastname3  1234567890
4            1  7725825       A       firstname4       lastname4  1234567890
5            2 11808809       A       firstname1       lastname1  1234567890
6            2  2236195       A       firstname2       lastname2  1234567891
  Date.Called Time.Called..EST.         starting_question        state call_ask
1    10/19/21      04:35 PM EST              Wrong Number pennsylvania     <NA>
2    10/19/21      04:28 PM EST              Not Home (1) pennsylvania     <NA>
3    10/19/21      04:33 PM EST               Refused (2) pennsylvania     <NA>
4    10/19/21      04:34 PM EST                    Hangup pennsylvania     <NA>
5    11/29/21      03:16 PM EST Talking to Correct Person      arizona      Yes
6    11/29/21      03:14 PM EST          Wrong Number (2)      arizona
```

There are quite a few columns that seem to have a lot of `NA`, but I assume that is the data? Regardless `unique(build_df$state)` returns:

`[1] "pennsylvania"   "arizona"        "north-carolina"`

with 535 total rows.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. So I tried reproducing this using my original script with the AWS bucket, but could not get it to work. So to make things as easy as possible, I created a dummy AWS bucket which I've provided the credentials for (It's a dummy account so there's zero sensitive data I need to worry about). Any chance you can edit your answer with this new information?

Comment: @wizkids121 I think my edit is doing what you want. The final df isn't equivalent to `final_df` in your post, but it looks like the data is different (ex. Wisconsin isn't in the AWS database, or at least isn't in one of the paths that you provide in `script_results`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use the built-in vector `state.name` to extract the state names using regex.

```
x = c("10162021-test-wisconsin-script_results-10-16-2020-568019545.csv",
"10192021-test-pennsylvania-script_results-10-19-2021-935649800.csv",
"11292021-test-arizona-script_results-11-29-2021-716199808.csv")

library(stringr)
(states = str_extract(x, paste(tolower(state.name), collapse = "|")))
# [1] "wisconsin"    "pennsylvania" "arizona"
```

Then, if you use set the list names to be the extracted state names, `dplyr::bind_rows` can add an ID column:

```
names(build_list) = states
build_df = dplyr::bind_rows(build_list, .id = "state")
```

---

In the context of your script:

```
all_buckets <-aws.s3::get_bucket_df(bucket = "test-bucket", max = Inf) %>% arrange(desc(LastModified))

#Filtering out some unnecessary files in the bucket (not super relevant to this question, but keeping it in to maintain script integrity)

buckets_format <- all_buckets %>% filter(str_detect(Key, '-Algorithm='))

buckets_script_results <- all_buckets %>% filter(str_detect(Key, '-script_results-')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '-Algorithm=')) %>% filter(!str_detect(Key, '2020'))

#Extracts the key needed to retrieve and open the CSV files in the bucket

script_results <- buckets_script_results$Key

#This is the actual extraction process where the files are downloaded and put into a dataframe.

build_list <- lapply(script_results, function(fn) aws.s3::s3read_using(read.csv, bucket="test-bucket", object=fn))


### NEW LINES
states = stringr::str_extract(x, paste(tolower(state.name), collapse = "|"))
names(build_list) = states
build_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(build_list, .id = "state")
## (assuming `archives` was a typo for `build_list`
##  since `build_list` doesn't come up again
##  and `archives` came out of nowhere)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I think you may have misread my question. I know how to extract the state name from the file name using Regex (though using `state.name` is new to me!) What I'm looking for is how to take the extracted state name from the file name and then create a column out of that to apply for each file that is being extracted.

Comment: Hmmm, when your question said *"what I'm trying to achieve is extracting the state from the file name (wisconsin, pennsylvania, arizona, etc...)"* it gave the impression you didn't know how to do that. I've added edits for adding the columns

Comment: Can you perhaps rewrite your answer in the larger context of my original script? While your answer is helpful as a one off, I'm not really sure how it can be applied within my original script.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm actually going to rewrite the question because I think worded it poorly. FWIW, your answer does not actually work correctly within the actual context of my script.

Comment: It's very hard to tell on my end. Looking forward to the rewrite.

Comment: Please see my rewritten question